# ArrayList InsertionSort problems

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, insertion

I'm attempting to make an Insertion sort program with an arraylist, but I'm getting errors on some of the things in it.

Whenever I try to run my program it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   5, Size: 5    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)   at
>   NewInsertionSort.main(NewInsertionSort.java:20)

But I don't understand where I'm calling something that it is "out of bounds".

Next, it says the value of my local variable "k" is never used, but it should be...

If anyone can help me, that would be great, thank you for any support.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NewInsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <Integer> InsertionSort = new ArrayList <Integer>(); 
        InsertionSort.add(1);
        InsertionSort.add(52);
        InsertionSort.add(21);
        InsertionSort.add(45);
        InsertionSort.add(27); 


        Integer a; 
        Integer lock; 
        Integer c; 
        for (c = 1; c < InsertionSort.size(); c++);{
            lock = InsertionSort.get(c); 
            System.out.println(lock); 


            for (a = c - 1; (a >= 0) && (InsertionSort.get(a) < lock); a--){
                 Integer k = InsertionSort.get(a+1); 
                 Integer h = InsertionSort.get(a);

                 k = h;   
            } 
            lock = InsertionSort.get(a+1);  

        }

        for(int z=0;z < InsertionSort.size(); z++){
            System.out.println(InsertionSort.get(z)); 
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (c = 1; c < InsertionSort.size(); c++) --> ; <-- {
            lock = InsertionSort.get(c); 
            System.out.println(lock);
```

Problem is that you have a ';' behind the closing ')' of your for loop. That's also reason why it tells you that variable k is not used.

**UPDATE based on commentary:**

The GET methods returns just the value under the 'a' position. So your 'k' and 'h' variables are just numbers. They do not point anywhere. If you want to assign value of 'a' to value of 'a+1' you have to do:

```
insertionSort.set(a+1, h);
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I didn't see it but it still says K isn't used?

Comment: Yeah .. because k isn't used. You assign value of h to variable k, but ... you don't use it after that. So it is pointless. I don't even understand why you assign to k then to h and after that you assign h to k ... you can remove h variable and assign InsertionSort.get(a); directly to k. But even then you have to use it somewhere in your code.

Comment: I'm trying to assign the value of a to the value of a+1 so I get both those values and make variables with them then set those variables equal to each other

Answer (score 0):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) is a zero based data structure (the linked Javadoc says in part that it throws an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) *if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())*). That means valid indexes are `0` to `n - 1` (where `n` is the `size`).

```
for (c = 1; c < InsertionSort.size(); c++) {
    lock = InsertionSort.get(c - 1);
```

**or**

```
for (c = 0; c < InsertionSort.size(); c++) {
    lock = InsertionSort.get(c);
```

Also, by convention, variable names start with a lower case letter. So `InsertionSort` should be `insertionSort` (or just `insertionList`). Finally, you might use the diamond operator in Java 7+ **and** you should program to the `List` *interface*. Something like,

```
List<Integer> insertionList = new ArrayList<>();
```